# Button is not working in Fragment activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to click the button to go from fragment to activity. But it is not working

this is fragment class
package com.hmat.foodrider;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;


public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {

  // go is start , request break button//



    public StatusFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = null;
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);

       Button go= (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button);
        go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StartActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });




        return v;
    }


}
```

That activity is working fine but I can not go from fragment to that activity using the button.

And this is the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSKXc.png)

Comment: Try to print a Toast or Log in onClick method.

Comment: that is not working also

Comment: Fragment Xml file?

Comment: Make sure you have a reference to the right button. Try changing its color programmatically in ‘oncreateview’. What does your layout file look like?

Answer (score 0):

**You can write :**
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);

**Instead of :**
startActivity(intent);

Comment: it was not working beacuse of duo tab viewer